# How do I access a random index inside an array

Tags: ios, arrays, variables, swift

I'm trying to access an array using random indexes by using `arc4random` to generate the random index. I'm sorry if my "technical usage of terms" are incorrect as I am fairly new to the development scene.

```
var backLeft = ["Clear","Drop","Smash"];    
var i = (arc4random()%(3))
var shot = backLeft[i]
```

This gives me an error on the third line,

```
Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments.
```

But, if I use,

```
var i = 2
var shot = backLeft[i]
```

Then it doesn't give me any issues. Coming from a php background, I can't seem to have any clue what's going wrong here.

Thank You! :) PS: I'm trying this on XCODE 6 inside the Swift Playground

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pick a random element from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003191/pick-a-random-element-from-an-array)

Comment: @Dschee, I think this question was posted before array.randomElement() was a thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's due to Swift's enforcement of type safety.

`arc4random()` returns a `UInt32`, and the subscript operator takes an `Int`.

You need to make sure `i` is of type `Int` before passing it into the subscript operator.

You can do so by initializing an `Int` from `i`:

```
var shot = backLeft[Int(i)]
```

Or, you can do the same to the random value before assigning it to `i` and then access `i` normally:

```
var i = Int(arc4random()%(3))
var shot = backLeft[i]
```

Comment: You can also cast the array length to Uint32 rather than hard coding it: arc4random() % UInt32(backLeft.count)

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 5, if you want to get a random element from an array, you can use `Array`'s [`randomElement()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994747-randomelement) method:

```
let array = ["Clear","Drop","Smash"]
let randomElement = array.randomElement()
print(String(describing: randomElement)) // Optional("Smash")
```

---

If you want to get a random index from an array, you can use `Array`'s [`indices`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994726-indices) property and `Range`'s [`randomElement()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/range/2996651-randomelement) method:

```
let array = ["Clear","Drop","Smash"]
let randomIndex = array.indices.randomElement()
print(String(describing: randomIndex)) // Optional(1)
```