# How do I make this extension of Array?

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to extend the `Array` type with a computed property called randElement, that's, obviously, returning a random element of the array, but I don't know how to deal with the fact that the type of elements that the `Array` contains.
Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
extension Array {
    var randElement:Array.Type {
        var randNumber = Double(arc4random())/Double(UInt32.max)
        randNumber*=(Double(self.count-1))
        randNumber = floor(randNumber)
        return self[Int(randNumber)]
    }
}
```

**It triggers me this error at the level of the return:**
`'T' is not convertible to 'Array<T>.Type`

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: This answer should be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24101606/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR I want to use a computed property rather than a function...

Comment: How, well, that's OK actually.

Comment: The main point is that `Array` is defined as `struct Array<T>` where `T` is the element type, so your function or property or whatever must return `T`.

Comment: Note also that `arc4random_uniform()` is generally preferred over `arc4random()`.

Comment: @MartinR How thank you for your information about `struct Array<T>`, know I understand why I can directly use T. And about `arc4random_uniform()`, I'm now using it based on what I saw on the other post.