# how to pick a random ten (String) from an array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

could anyone teach me how to select an item (`String`) from an array by using `arc4random_uniform()`? I tried but I couldn't because `arc4random_uniform` can be used for selecting Int.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003191/pick-a-random-element-from-an-array

Comment: Basically as shown in the question above, you just have to declare the random number as a Integer like so `Int(randomNumber)` That makes the type of your number an integer instead of a UInt32

Comment: i mean how can i chage String form into Integer?

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3 Extension**

While Oisdk answer works, a extension could be more useful instead of writing that coding over and over again.

```
import Foundation

extension Array {

  func randomElement() -> Element  {
     if isEmpty { return nil }
     return self[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.count)))]
  }
}

let myArray = ["dog","cat","bird"]

myArray.randomElement() //dog 
myArray.randomElement() //dog 
myArray.randomElement() //cat 
myArray.randomElement() //bird
```

Answer (score 2):

Subscripting an array takes and Int, but arc4random_uniform returns a UInt32. So you just need to convert between those types.

```
import Foundation

let array = ["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"]

let randomItem = array[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))]
```

Also, arc4random_uniform gives a random number less that its argument. So just cast array.count to a UInt32, and it'll work.

Comment: This will crash if there are no items.