# Spawning a circle in a random spot on screen

Tags: ios, swift, random, arc4random

I've been racking my brain and searching here and all over to try to find out how to generate a random position on screen to spawn a circle. I'm hoping someone here can help me because I'm completely stumped. Basically, I'm trying to create a shape that always spawns in a random spot on screen when the user touches.

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width

        let currentBall = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 100)
        currentBall.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Float(screenWidth)))), CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Float(screenHeight)))))

        self.removeAllChildren()
        self.addChild(currentBall)
}
```

If you all need more of my code, there really isn't any more. But thank you for whatever help you can give! (Just to reiterate, this code kind of works... But a majority of the spawned balls seem to spawn offscreen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem there is that you scene is bigger than your screen bounds

```
let viewMidX = view!.bounds.midX
let viewMidY = view!.bounds.midY
print(viewMidX)
print(viewMidY)

let sceneHeight = view!.scene!.frame.height
let sceneWidth = view!.scene!.frame.width
print(sceneWidth)
print(sceneHeight)

let currentBall = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 100)
currentBall.fillColor = .green

let x = view!.scene!.frame.midX - viewMidX + CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(viewMidX*2)))
let y = view!.scene!.frame.midY - viewMidY + CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(viewMidY*2)))
print(x)
print(y)

currentBall.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
view?.scene?.addChild(currentBall)

self.removeAllChildren()
self.addChild(currentBall)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, works exactly like I want it too. And you didn't change my code much so it's easy to understand. Thank you! (I'm fairly new to swift so this is a huge help)

Comment: @LeoDabus what should I do if I just want to add balls? I don't want to lose previous balls by calling self.removeAll

Comment: Thanks, never mind, I solved my problem like this: 1) shift = self.frame.width / 2 - view.bounds.width/2
        2) let frame = CGRectMake(shift, 0, self.view!.bounds.width, self.view!.bounds.height)
      3)  let sceneBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: frame)

Answer (score 1):

First: Determine the area that will be valid. It might not be the frame of the superview because perhaps the ball (let's call it `ballView`) might be cut off. The area will likely be (in *pseudocode*):

```
CGSize( Width of the superview - width of ballView , Height of the superview - height of ballView)
```

Once you have a view of that size, just place it on screen with the `origin` 0, 0.

Secondly: Now you have a range of valid coordinates. Just use a random function (like the one you are using) to select one of them.

Create a swift file with the following:

```
extension Int
{
    static func random(range: Range<Int>) -> Int
    {
        var offset = 0

        if range.startIndex < 0   // allow negative ranges
        {
            offset = abs(range.startIndex)
        }

        let mini = UInt32(range.startIndex + offset)
        let maxi = UInt32(range.endIndex   + offset)

        return Int(mini + arc4random_uniform(maxi - mini)) - offset
    }
}
```

And now you can specify a random number as follows:

```
Int.random(1...1000) //generate a random number integer somewhere from 1 to 1000.
```

You can generate the values for the x and y coordinates now using this function.

Comment: Not sure that pulling a random `Int` from a `Range<Int>` is the best approach for this question, but if `random(Range<Int>)` is what you want, there is a way of implementing it without risking an integer overflow – see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30285125/1409907).

Answer (score 0):

Given the following random generators:

```
public extension CGFloat {
    public static var random: CGFloat { return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max) }

    public static func random(between x: CGFloat, and y: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let (start, end) = x < y ? (x, y) : (y, x)
        return start + CGFloat.random * (end - start)
    }
}

public extension CGRect {
    public var randomPoint: CGPoint {
        var point = CGPoint()
        point.x = CGFloat.random(between: origin.x, and: origin.x + width)
        point.y = CGFloat.random(between: origin.y, and: origin.y + height)
        return point
    }
}
```

You can paste the following into a playground:

```
import XCPlayground
import SpriteKit

let view = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
XCPShowView("game", view)

let scene = SKScene(size: view.frame.size)
view.presentScene(scene)

let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)
let popIn = SKAction.scaleTo(1, duration: 0.25)
let popOut = SKAction.scaleTo(0, duration: 0.25)
let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

let popInAndOut = SKAction.sequence([popIn, wait, popOut, remove])

let addBall = SKAction.runBlock { [unowned scene] in
    let ballRadius: CGFloat = 25
    let ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: ballRadius)
    var popInArea = scene.frame
    popInArea.inset(dx: ballRadius, dy: ballRadius)
    ball.position = popInArea.randomPoint
    ball.xScale = 0
    ball.yScale = 0
    ball.runAction(popInAndOut)
    scene.addChild(ball)
}

scene.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([addBall, wait])))
```

(Just make sure to also paste in the random generators, too, or to copy them to the playground's `Sources`, as well as to open the assistant editor so you can see the animation.)

Comment: Though I no longer need help with the random ball, is the `XCPlayground` sort of like an emulator for the iOS simulator? Like, does it allow you to open views like one would in an iOS project? Or am I just being hopeful?

Comment: The code above will run directly in the playground with OS X as the platform selected in the Playground Settings. This being SpriteKit and CoreGraphics, it should also work just as well in an iOS app (though I haven't tried). Playgrounds can run it in the simulator, too, with the "Run in Full Simulator" checkbox selected in the settings...