# Pulling random string from array with arc4random_uniform in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, arc4random

When I run the app, I keep getting the error:

```
"Could not cast value of type 'Swift._NSContiguousString' to 'NSArray'."
```

I've tried casting to a `String` as well, but that obviously wasn't the solution either. Has anyone encounter this? I'm just trying to pull a random string from the array.

```
firstArray = ["firstItem", "secondItem", "thirdItem"]
randomArray = firstArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(firstArray.count)))] as! NSArray
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is the declaration of `randomArray`?

Comment: I declared it globally, above the function.

Comment: please provide it declaration.

Comment: var randomArray: NSArray!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pick a random element from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003191/pick-a-random-element-from-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your array defined as the following :

```
var firstArray = ["firstItem", "secondItem", "thirdItem"]
```

Then do the random number from here :

```
 let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(firstArray.count)))
```

Get the result like this :

```
var result = self.firstArray[randomIndex]
```

Good luck !