# Get Random String from an Array

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to get a random string from array "firstArray" and print it in UILabel "label". I cannot seem to figure it out and I get errors. Your help is appreciated. I tried searching but could not find any up-to-date tutorials/methods.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func random(_ sender: Any) {
        let firstArray = [ "hi" , "bye" , "hello"]
    }
```

Comment: Update your question with the code causing the error and post the error message.

Comment: your question is not a really bad question, so i won't downvote it. But you really need to post more info, like how you implement the 'random' function. (cause i do not see any random algo. from you code, you just defined a array of string)

Comment: analyses the code before post for proper basic opening and closing brackets at least.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: [Pick a random element from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003191/pick-a-random-element-from-an-array).

Comment: One tip to improve your code is, don't name your `IBAction` method `random`, you see people don't even know where you want to implement the random function. Write another function called `random`, then put it inside that `IBAction`, it'll be easier for you to read later on :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rather using `arc4random()`, this code will pick up random items from your array:

```
let firstArray = ["hi", "bye", "hello"]
    let randomItem = Int(arc4random() % UInt32(firstArray.count))
    myLabel.text = "\(firstArray[randomItem])"
```

Comment: This makes no attempt to get a random value from the array and it assigns the random `Int` to the label.

Comment: yep, mistyped error, i've forgot the firstArray[] before \(randomItem) :)

Comment: Please avoid posting code-only answers. Try to explain how your code solves the OP's problem, and help others who are less experienced understand your solution.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @fvimagination  its not working in swift 4 would you provide an update?

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate random numbers between 0 and your array count, then set the label text to the corresponding item in array, like this:

```
@IBAction func random(_ sender: UIButton) {
     let firstArray = [ "hi" , "bye" , "hello"]
     var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(firstArray.count)))
     randLabel.text = firstArray[randomNumber]
}
```

this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007129/how-does-one-generate-a-random-number-in-apples-swift-language) is helpful to understand the random logic.