# how to generate random string with arc4random in swift?? It is possible?

Tags: swift, arc4random

[what's wrong? How I can generate words or string with arc4random?? Thank you for the help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTZ5X.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pick a random element from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003191/pick-a-random-element-from-an-array)

Answer (score -1):

You have to restrict the results of arc4random to the length of your array.

```
array1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array1.count)))]
```