# 'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int, see the documentation comment for discussion

Tags: ios, swift

[ScreenShot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLTDs.png)

I want to change the color the selected String from the cell.
some chunks of code given below to more help to me.

*`'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int, see the documentation comment for discussion`*

```
{
    let Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath)as! FirstTableViewCell
    Cell.selectionStyle = .none

    Cell.marqueeLabel1.type = .continuous
    Cell.marqueeLabel1.animationCurve = .easeInOut

    let strings = "Purchase bids- 0123456789     Sell Bids- 0123456789     Cleared- 0123456789     "

    let txtfield1 :UITextField!

    let string_to_color = "0123456789"

    let range = (strings as NSString).range(of: string_to_color)

    let attribute = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: strings)
    attribute.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red , range: range)

    txtfield1 = UITextField.init(frame:CGRect(x:10 , y:20 ,width:100 , height:100))
    txtfield1.attributedText = attribute

    Cell.marqueeLabel1.text = strings[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(strings.count)))]
    Cell.marqueeLabel2.type = .continuous
    Cell.marqueeLabel2.animationCurve = .easeInOut
    let strings2 = ["Purchase bids- 0123456789     Sell Bids- 0123456789     Cleared- 0123456789     "]

    // Cell.marqueeLabel2.text = strings[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(strings2.count)))]

    return Cell
}
```

Comment: can you clarify your question and your issue. Like which line is having an issue?

Comment: Cell.marqueeLabel1.text = strings[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(strings.count)))] .       this line is showing an error 'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int, see the documentation comment for discussion i also have added a screenshot link above in first line of title "enter image description here".

Comment: see your strings array,

Comment: let strings = "Purchase bids- 0123456789,     Sell Bids- 0123456789  ,   Cleared- 0123456789,     "

Comment: on adding strings array it shows an error of  '[String]' is not convertible to 'NSString' in this line             let range = (strings as NSString).range(of: string_to_color)

Comment: can any one help me out on teamviewer?

Comment: try simply as let arrayString = ["1","2","3","4"]

Comment: and see  and then screenshot to the qustion

Comment: Your `let strings` is **NOT** an array of strings, it's just a string...

Comment: yea right @EricAya

Comment: it shows same error after adding a array also,here i just want to change the selected text color

Answer (score 0):

[try!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003191/pick-a-random-element-from-an-array)
unlike your string array 
like,

```
let array = ["Frodo", "sam", "wise", "gamgee"]
 Cell.marqueeLabel1.text = array [Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working (you need to use the subscript methods as in doc: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html#ID494):

```
let strings = " 1234 1234 4567"
let myString = strings[strings.index(strings.startIndex, offsetBy: String.IndexDistance(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(strings.characters.count))))]
```

Comment: is it telling you that it cannot convert value of type Character to type String?
By the way,why  are you even trying to get a random character from strings? what's the purpose in what you try to do?

Comment: I am not trying to get any random character I just want to change the color of the selected string from a string array of a marquee Label

Comment: you do not have a string array but one long string. What you are doing right now (and what is giving you the warning) is taking a random character within that long string (your variable strings) and assigning it to the text of the cell. Is it really something you need to do?

Comment: here in the code just suggest me to change the color of a string "0123456789" from that one long string .  as i am using a third party of a marquee label;