# Changing a string into a variable in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I have an `array` is of the form

```
var array = ["cat1", "cat2", "cat3"]
```

I would like to be able to randomly choose one of these elements, where each element is the actual name of another array.

So I also have

`var cat1 = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"]` basically an array of questions.

this is a similar format for `cat2` and `cat3`.

Now the reason I want this is to randomly choose a topic for questions, then select a question from the chosen array, my problem is I don't know how to programmatically use, say for example,

```
cat2[1]
```

I basically want to display the contents of the element that is chosen.

Is this at all possible? I have been trying to get this to play nice for a while now :(

Thank you!

Comment: is user will choose the cate1 cate2 etc?

Comment: i think the correct way is to use dictionary for your questions.

Comment: @LeeMckelvey you can use a dictionary where in each key will correspond to and array of question more like ["cat1" : ["Q1","Q2","Q3"], "cat2" : ["Q1","Q2","Q3"]];

Comment: @Salman, no the user will not choose, it is to be random.

Comment: So i think you want to make dynamic variable right?

Comment: @Salman thank you, all done now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an array of arrays and not `Strings`. For example:

```
var cat1 = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"]
var cat2 = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"]
var cat3 = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"]

var array = [cat1, cat2, cat3]
```

Or a two-dimensional array:

```
var array = [["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"], ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"], ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"]]
```

Then you can randomly choose a "line" and then the question from it:

```
var question = array[randomNumber][questionNumber]
```

Another alternative is to use a `Dictionary`. Then you will have this structure:

```
var dict = ["cat1" : ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"],
            "cat2" : ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"],
            "cat3" : ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"]]
```

Comment: I triedvar array = [["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"], ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"], ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"]] but when I try print(array[0][0]) I get ["Q1","Q2","Q3"]

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use it like this--

var cat1 = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"]

var cat2 = ["Q4", "Q5", "Q6"]

var cat3 = ["Q7", "Q8", "Q9"]

var array = [cat1, cat2, cat3]

print(array[0][0])

print(cat[1])

-------------------
the answer would be :--- Q1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use array of arrays, like

```
var cat1 = ["Q1", "Q2"]
var cat2 = ["Q10", "Q11"]
var cat3 = ["Q20", "Q21"]
var array = [cat1, cat2, cat3]
```

And chose randomly one object from `array` and that one object will be one of `cat1`, `cat2` or `cat3` and that represents the array of questions

---

Edit: Seems that these are your instance variable either initialize them in `viweDidLoad` if it's in view controller or use the below code

```
var array = [["Q1", "Q2"],
             ["Q10", "Q11"],
             ["Q20", "Q21"]]
```

Comment: When I try this it tells me "cannot use instance member 'cat1', within property initialiser; property initialisers run before 'self' is available."

Comment: Is there a specific way to write arrays inside arrays?

Comment: I've edited answer, is this code in a viewController then you can also create ivars as optionals and assign values in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

type can either use a `[[String]]` or create a custom class for that.

To use a `[[String]]`, first declare the arrays `cat1`, `cat2` and `cat3`:

```
let cat1 = [...]
let cat2 = [...]
let cat3 = [...]
```

Then you simply do this:

```
let array = [cat1, cat2, cat3] // without the ""s!
```

Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003191/pick-a-random-element-from-an-array) for how to select a random item.

You basically select a random item from `array`, put the result into an array called `randomTopic` or whatever, then choose another random item from `randomTopic`.

---

Alternatively, you can create a type to store questions.

```
struct Topic {
    let questions: [String]
}
```

Then you create an array of `Topic` i.e. `[Topic]` and do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Please below code and check the demo too.

```
/* DECLARING ALL THE QUESTION ARRAYS */
var cat1 = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5"],
    cat2 = ["Q6", "Q7"],
    cat3 = ["Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q13"],
        /* DECLARING ALL THE QUESTION ARRAYS INTO ANOTHER SINGLE ARRAY */
        array = [cat1, cat2, cat3];

/* SELECTING WHICH QUESTION ARRAY TO PICK EITHER CAT1, CAT2 OR CAT3 USING MATH RONDOM FUNCTION */
var whichQuestionArray = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)],
    /* PICKING WHICH QUESTION TO SHOW FROM ABOVE ANSWER */
    selectedQuestion = whichQuestionArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * whichQuestionArray.length)];
/* PRINTING THE OUTPUT IN THE CONSOLE */
console.log("Selected Question - " + selectedQuestion);
```

Demo [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/sncq1m6g/19/)