# Play random sound from an array in Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, audio, swift3

I have a single sound file playing at the start of my game:

```
    // Play the start sound:
    self.run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Sound/StartGame.aif", waitForCompletion: false))
```

How do I get a random single sound file from an array to play instead?

Comment: check out the answer and let me know if u have any confusion..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pick a random element from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003191/pick-a-random-element-from-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all, you have to add all sound name in the array and get the random name of sound from the array.**

```
let arrSound = ["Sound/StartGame.aif","Sound/StartGame2.aif"]
```

**Get the random name of sound.**

```
let randomSound = arrSound[Int(arc4random_uniform(arrSound.count))]

self.run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed(randomSound, waitForCompletion: false))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let soundNames = ["soundName1", "soundName2", "soundName3"]
let randomSoundName = soundNames[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(soundNames.count)))]

let randomSound = self.run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed(randomSoundName, waitForCompletion: false))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a array containing all the music file names `eg.Sound/StartGame.aif` and pick one randomly when you need to play sound.