# Random color when score +10

Tags: ios, swift

I have few colors in my game:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
let colors = [SKColor.green, SKColor.red, SKColor.blue, SKColor.magenta, SKColor.yellow, SKColor.brown]
```

I want if my thing in the game change color (from one of above) every time when score +10.

How possible to make it simple way like?

```
score += 10
thing.fillColor = .random
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003191/pick-a-random-element-from-an-array

Comment: what fill color type of thing is?

Comment: where you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want if my thing in the game change color (from one of above) every time when score +10.

When you don't know how to do something, try to break it down into smaller problems. You want to change to a random color when the score changes, and that entails several smaller things:

- choose a random color
- set the color
- do something when the score increases by some delta

So let's take the just the first part and break that down further. To choose a random color from your array, we need to:

- figure out how many colors are in the array
- pick a random number between zero and the array size
- get the color corresponding to that number

When you break it down into very small steps like that, it's not hard to figure out how to write each line, even if you have to search online for some answers. Code to do the above might look like:

```
let colors = [SKColor.green, SKColor.red, SKColor.blue, SKColor.magenta, SKColor.yellow, SKColor.brown]
let numberOfColors = colors.count
let colorIndex = Int.random(in:0 ..< numberOfColors)
let newColor = colors[colorIndex]
```

If you're using an older version of Swift, you'll need to use a different function to pick a random number, and that'll require a bit of casting, but it's still pretty simple:

```
let colors = [SKColor.green, SKColor.red, SKColor.blue, SKColor.magenta, SKColor.yellow, SKColor.brown]
let numberOfColors = colors.count
let colorIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(numberOfColors)))
let newColor = colors[colorIndex]
```

You can combine some of those steps as you get more comfortable, so that you don't need so many intermediate variables, but small steps will help keep problems small and easy to understand.

Once you've picked a random color, you need to figure out how to use it to set the background color. A SpriteKit scene is a `SKScene`, and a scene is displayed in a `SKView`. If you look at the docs for `SKScene`, you'll find that the scene has a reference to the view in which it's displayed, and the view (because it's a subclass of `UIView`) has a `backgroundColor` property that you can set. Luckily, `backgroundColor` wants a `UIColor`, and `SKColor` is an alias for `UIColor`. So, let's say you have a scene called `gameScene`, and you've already picked a new color as above...

```
let view = gameScene.view
view.backgroundColor = newColor
```

or just:

```
gameScene.view.backgroundColor = newColor
```

You say you want this color change to happen when the score increases by 10. The first thing to think about is how to do *anything* when the score increases by some amount? How does the score ever change? Hopefully, there's just one part of your code that's responsible for updating the score. If so, that'd be a good place to insert code that does things that should happen when the score changes. If the score always changes by one point at a time, as in baseball, then you can keep it really simple and just change the background color when the score is a multiple of 10 (or whatever delta you choose):

```
if game.score % 10 == 0 {
    game.changeColors()
}
```

But if the score can increase by more than one point at a time, as it does in football, then that simple strategy won't work because a single change might skip right over the condition that makes the color change happen. One way to handle that is to keep track of what the score was the last time you changed the color:

```
if game.score - game.scoreAtLastColorChange >= 10 {
    game.changeColors()
    game.scoreAtLastColorChange = game.score
}
```

I hope that helps. Just keep breaking the problem down into smaller steps.

Comment: Thank you deeply for the lesson! I'll definitely use it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
public func randomColorWithOpacity(opacity: CGFloat) -> UIColor {

    let r: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(255)
    let g: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(255)
    let b: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(255)

    return UIColor(red: CGFloat(r) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(g) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(b) / 255.0, alpha: opacity)
}

thing.fillColor = randomColorWithOpacity(opacity: 1.0)
```

Try this function for Color

Answer (score 0):

Try this one may help you.

**Function Definition**

```
func confirmColorChange(score:Int,oldScore:Int)->Bool{
    if (score - oldScore) % 10 == 0{
           return true
    }
    return false
}
```

**Calling Method** with sample for loop increment.
**Swift 4.1 and below**

```
var score = 2
var oldScore = score
let colors = [SKColor.green, SKColor.red, SKColor.blue, SKColor.magenta, SKColor.yellow, SKColor.brown]
//Sample Increased for Loop
for i in 0 ..< 100 {
   score = score + i
   if self.confirmColorChange(score: score, oldScore: oldScore){
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colors.count)))
         let radomColor = colors[randomIndex] //Set a color where you want 
   }
   oldScore = score
}
```

**Calling Method** with sample for loop increment.
**Swift 4.2 and above**

```
var score = 2
var oldScore = score
let colors = [SKColor.green, SKColor.red, SKColor.blue, SKColor.magenta, SKColor.yellow, SKColor.brown]
//Sample Increased for Loop
for i in 0 ..< 100 {
   score = score + i
   if self.confirmColorChange(score: score, oldScore: oldScore){
        let radomColor = colors.randomElement() //Set a color where you want 
   }
   oldScore = score
}
```